# Compiling Silverlight runtime question

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-2.0

I have created a Silverlight project which also contains a Web project.

I have a few class files in my web project which use System.Windows.Point and System.Windows.Size data types and I am getting compile errors when I try to pass either of these types in a List like `List<Point>` in the Silverlight project.  If I try without the `List<>` I still get the Point data type error.

I reviewed information about compiling Silverlight assemblies from [David Betz](http://www.netfxharmonics.com/2008/12/Reusing-NET-Assemblies-in-Silverlight) site I found a [tool](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SLAssemblies.aspx) to help me used the first of the two approaches he discusses and have successfully compiled the runtime and referenced it in my Silverlight project.

Here are the errors:

- The type 'System.Windows.Point' is
  defined in an assembly that is not
  referenced. You must add a reference
  to assembly 'WindowsBase,
  Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
  PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.    C:\Documents
  and Settings\Gary\My Documents\Visual
  Studio
  2008\Projects\GEP.Reports.Spatial\GEP.Reports.Spatial\MainPage.xaml.cs
- cannot convert from
  'System.Collections.Generic.List
  [c:\Program Files\Reference
  Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v3.0\mscorlib.dll]'
  to
  'System.Collections.Generic.List
  [c:\Program Files\Reference
  Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v3.0\mscorlib.dll]

What step am I missing in order to get these types added to my Silverlight runtime.

Thanks for any help.

Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple types like Point and Size you are better off rolling your own structs/classes rather than trying to find ways of referencing non-Silverlight assemblies. In addition you don't really want something like the System.Windows assembly being included in your .xap for the sake of something like the Point struct.

Comment: I created a struct but when I actually needed to use System.Windows.Point in code I got an error stating something like "could not convert <my namespace>.<struct name> to System.Windows.Point".  I tried casting to a point but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Actually I just checked and the Point struct is in the Silverlight libraries so you don't need to create it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.point(VS.95).aspx. Do you have a refence to System.Windows in your SL project?

Answer (score 0):

actually you can use System.Windows.Point. Just in your WS use **SL** dll:

C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\WindowsBase.dll